# How to recover a column from another spreadsheet based on criteria

Tags: excel

I'm a kind of a noob at excel and it's my first time on this site, so I will formulate my question as best I can.

I have spreadsheet `A` with :

```
Column A : ID (ID01 , ID 02 , ID 03)
Column B : Values (from 0 to 2 for each ID)
```

Spreadsheet `B` has no data, and I want to import the values from Column A onto the Column A of Spreadsheet B, where `ID >= 1`.

I tried some stuff, but since I'm bad with nested formulas nothing worked.

Thanks in advance for whatever help you can provide!

Comment: Add the formula that you tried with your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Sheet1` is as follows

[image]

Then, in `Cell A2` of `Sheet2` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$11, SMALL(IF((INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$11, ,2, 1)>0), MATCH(ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$11), ROW(Sheet1!$A$2:$D$11)), ""), ROWS(Sheet1!A2:$A$2)), , 1),"")
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as required. Change range as needed. See image for reference.

[image]

For details on array formula see [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d).